# bindIntoStack error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I get a javascript error and cannot understand what is going on. Did anyone get such error?

```
$("input[type=text],input[type=password],input[type=checkbox],input[type=radio],select,textarea").bindIntoStack is not a function
Source: http://localhost:54838/GP.Portal.Ugur/default.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fGP.Portal.Ugur%2fapp%2fDefault.aspx
Error: 380
```

Comment: The function was hidden in a framework that I was using. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

That is because `bindIntoStack` is **not** a function...

Make sure to include the libraries for it.